# Prevent Dialogue Submission from Refreshing Page

Tags: jquery, html

I have a Dialog Popup that is supposed to append information to a table. In Chrome it appends it once and then on the second time refreshes the page and clears everything.

I have tried

```
        $('#addthisquote').submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
```

Moving the prevent default at top and bottom, neither worked. Also Within the HTML

```
  <div data-role="page" data-external="false">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SteveRobertson/p6bCW/10/

I have attached a JSfiddle, which refreshes the page every time. Is There anyway to prevent this behavior preferably without using ajax due to my lack of understanding of ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After fiddling with your fiddle, it seems you forgot to things, first add the starting `$` to the `$(document).ready(` call:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
^-------- YOU FORGOT THIS
```

And also you need to return `false` at the end of the submit handler to make sure the form is not submitted.

See [**working fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/gnel/p6bCW/9/)

Comment: o I feel silly on forgetting the $ sign. I had just updated that seconds before your answer. You are the best nelson. I have seen this question asked a few times with no simple solution. Thanks